# Table on ASP website loses formatting

Tags: asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

Okay, so maybe one of you can figure out what is going on here. On our ASP website, we have a table presents information about a user like so:

[image: Screenshot 1, formatted table]

There is a link on the page the produces a pop-up menu that allows the user to email the link to this page to a friend. After the user clicks the "Close" button on the pop-up form, however, this table loses its formatting and displays as such:

[image: Screenshot 2, unformatted table]

I've been able to trace the problem as far as the ajaxcontroltoolkit, in which the following function is being ran:

```
AjaxControlToolkit.HTMLEditor.addFormOnSubmit=function(e,d)
{
    var b="undefined",a=null,c=window.theForm;
    if(window.theForm!=a&&typeof window.theForm!=b)
    {
        if(c.AjaxControlToolkit_HTMLEditor_editPanels==a||typeof c.AjaxControlToolkit_HTMLEditor_editPanels==b)
        {
            c.originalOnSubmit_AjaxControlToolkit_HTMLEditor=window.theForm.onsubmit;
            c.AjaxControlToolkit_HTMLEditor_editPanels=[];
            window.theForm.onsubmit=AjaxControlToolkit.HTMLEditor.EditPanelsOnSubmit;
            if(window.__doPostBack!=a&&typeof window.__doPostBack!=b)
            if(window.__doPostBack_AjaxControlToolkit_HTMLEditor_original==a||typeof window.__doPostBack_AjaxControlToolkit_HTMLEditor_original==b)
            {
                window.__doPostBack_AjaxControlToolkit_HTMLEditor_original=window.__doPostBack;
                window.__doPostBack=AjaxControlToolkit.HTMLEditor.EditPanelsOnPostBack
            }
            if(window.ValidatorGetValue!=a&&typeof window.ValidatorGetValue!=b)
            if(window.ValidatorGetValue_AjaxControlToolkit_HTMLEditor_original==a||typeof window.ValidatorGetValue_AjaxControlToolkit_HTMLEditor_original==b)
            {window.ValidatorGetValue_AjaxControlToolkit_HTMLEditor_original=window.ValidatorGetValue;window.ValidatorGetValue=AjaxControlToolkit.HTMLEditor.ValidatorGetValue}
        }
        c.AjaxControlToolkit_HTMLEditor_editPanels.push({handler:e,editPanel:d})
    }
};
```

I should note that this is happening in all major browsers and not isolated to a single browser. Additionally, I believe that it is hitting this function because when I hover over the close button, I see `javascript:__doPostBack('main_content_0$Close','')`

I am at a loss for what is going on here and why this table is losing it's formatting. If anyone could help, it would be much appreciated.

The code in the ascx file creating the table:

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <asp:Placeholder runat="server" Visible='<%# IsNewGroup((string)DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "GroupTitle")) %>'>
        <tr>
            <td style="font-weight: bold; padding-left: 5px; border-bottom: 1px solid black;">
                <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "GroupTitle") %>
            </td>
            <td style="font-weight: bold; border-bottom: 1px solid black;">
                Date Earned
            </td>
            <td style="font-weight: bold; border-bottom: 1px solid black;">
                Status
            </td>
        </tr>
    </asp:Placeholder>
    <tr>
        <td>
            &nbsp;
            <%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "CredentialName")%>
        </td>
        <td class="text_center">
            <%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "DateEarned")%>
        </td>
        <td>
            <%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Status")%>
        </td>
    </tr>
</ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: Are you generating the table at runtime?

Comment: Is the problem occurring on different types of browsers?

Comment: Bhavesh, the code is being created from the ascx file for the page, I have edited the question to include this code.

Comment: Felice, it is happening in all major browsers. I have tested against IE(7,9,10,11), FireFox, Chrome, Opera, and Safari.

Comment: Are you rebinding the gridview on `:__doPostBack('main_content_0$Close','')`?

Comment: I do not believe so but I am not 100% sure on that. How would I be able to tell? It appears as if the whole page refreshes when the close button is hit, just without the html to format the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that this issue was unrelated to AJAX. The problem was due to a bad IF/ELSE statement in the page load function of the page in the C# code; it wasn't properly binding the table data items on the page when the page was postback. On correcting this issue, the page now works fine.